# C++ Template const char array to int

Tags: c++, string, templates

So, I'm wishing to be able to have a static const compile 
time struct that holds some value based on a string by using
templates. I only desire up to four characters. I know that
the type of 'abcd' is `int`, and so is 'ab','abc', and although
'a' is of type `char`, it works out for a `template<int v> struct`

What I wish to do is take sizes of 2,3,4,5 of some const char, "abcd"
and have the same functionality as if they used 'abcd'. *Note that
I do not mean 1,2,3, or 4 because I expect the null terminator.*

`cout << typeid("abcd").name() << endl;`  tells me that the type for
this hard coded string is `char const [5]`, which includes the null 
terminator on the end.

I understand that I will need to twiddle the values as characters,
so they are represented as an integer.

I cannot use `constexpr` since VS10 does not support it (VS11 doesn't either..)

So, for example with somewhere this template defined, and later the last line

```
template <int v> struct something {
    static const int value = v;
};

//Eventually in some method
cout << typeid(something<'abcd'>::value).name() << endl;
```

works just fine.

I've tried

```
template<char v[5]> struct something2 {
    static const int value = v[0];
}

template<char const v[5]> struct something2 {
    static const int value = v[0];
}

template<const char v[5]> struct something2 {
    static const int value = v[0];
}
```

All of them build individually, though when I throw in my test,

```
cout << typeid(something2<"abcd">::value).name() << endl;
```

I get

```
'something2' : invalid expression as a template argument for 'v'
'something2' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

---

Is this not feasible or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If it is viable to, e.g., write `something<"1234"_LS>` you can turn the string into a `constexpr int`.

Comment: @dietmar-kuhl `_LS` is not viable because of VS10, or at least my attempt resulted in `'_LS' : undeclared identifier`.
I would like the ability to take a known range of character sizes and just have a hash that will be used later, but in the same template.
This has to do with something like a tuple but set up with database hooks by just the types and primary key, which can be selected at compile time by grabbing a typedef from a struct specialized with the given string.

Comment: Well, `_LS` is undeclared, of course: it is a suffix for a user-defined literal: you'd need to define it first. However, these can take strings and analyse them obe character at a time. I don't know if VC++ supports user-defined literals.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, Ah, after looking it up, I see what you mean now. 

It doesn't seem that VS10 or VS11 support variadic templates..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14.1 lists the acceptable types of non-type template arguments:

> — integral or enumeration type,
>   — pointer to object or pointer to function,
>   — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>   — pointer to member,

Arrays don't fit under any of these categories.

14.3.2/1 lists categories of what's permitted as template arguments and 14.3.2/2 goes on to say:

> Note: A string literal (2.14.5) does not satisfy the requirements of any of these categories and thus is not an acceptable template-argument.

Therefore you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, from the standard.

14.3.2.1:

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - the address of an object or function with external linkage, including function templates >and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed as & id->expression where the & is optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the >corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1 .

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get close to what you are wanting.  Possibly this will work for you, although it adds an extra level of code to be maintained.

It requires defining const char arrays with external linkage, then using the names of those arrays to instantiate classes from the templates.  Of course in real use this code would be separated into various .h and .cpp files.

```
extern const char a[] = "a";
extern const char b[] = "b";
extern const char ab[] = "ab";
extern const char abc[] = "abc";

template <const char * const  T> class Test
{
public:
    Test() {str = typename T;};
private:
    const char * str;
};


SomeFunction()
{
    Test<a> A;
    Test<b> B;
    Test<ab> AB;
    Test<abc> ABC;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting workaround..
I'll try to look into it after I get normal ints which can be represented by `abcd` working.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not trying to take credit for discovering this technique.  I probably first saw it at http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#stringliteral  and I have never actually used it in production code. There are other references to it here on SO.